# Can t-tests be 1 sided? This example has confused what I thought I knew.

Tags: hypothesis-testing

We first take a random sample of $8$ students, record their final score in $2018$, and check their final scores again in $2019$.

$2018: 76, 73, 66, 95, 75, 78, 96, 93$

$2019: 75, 80, 70, 93, 81, 90, 88, 79$

We're testing whether the grades have improved for these 8 students.

Since we're looking to see if the grades have "improved", aren't we looking for evidence that they have increased and not decreased?

These are the null and alternative hypotheses I wrote up to convey my reasoning:

$H$<sub>$0$</sub> : $μ$<sub>1</sub> $-$ $μ$<sub>2</sub> ≥ $0$

$H$<sub>$1$</sub> : $μ$<sub>1</sub> $-$ $μ$<sub>2</sub> < $0$

From what I know, the alternative hypothesis always has to hold the remaining outcomes dictated by the null hypothesis, hence my confusion.

I was told the correct hypotheses tests were:

$H$<sub>$0$</sub> : $μ$<sub>1</sub> $=$ $μ$<sub>2</sub>

$H$<sub>$1$</sub> : $μ$<sub>1</sub> $≠$ $μ$<sub>2</sub>

I'm sure the word 'improved' has to affect the direction of the hypotheses tests of this t-test but I don't know anymore.

Thanks

Comment: Are the upvotes saying I'm right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-sided $t$-tests absolutely do exist and are valid hypothesis tests, just as we also have one-sided $z$-tests.

I disagree with the claimed hypothesis and agree with yours.  If $\mu_1$ is the mean score in 2018 and $\mu_2$ is the mean score in $2019$, then your hypothesis is structured correctly for testing whether the scores improved in from 2018 to 2019.  The other hypothesis could potentially conclude that a difference exists but without examining the sign of the test statistic, it would not tell you whether that difference is due to improvement.  In other words, if all I saw is the $p$-value from that test, I could not tell you whether the scores improved or not.

Another subtlety here is that this is a *paired* $t$-test, so we are not really testing whether the mean scores have improved, but rather, whether the mean *difference* in scores improved.  Each student is their own control, and what is following a $t$-distribution is the difference between their 2018 score and 2019 score.  As such, the scores themselves do not need to be $t$-distributed, but their differences do.